# 401 Unauthorized when consuming Business Central OData Web Service in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, api, web-services, odata, dynamics-business-central

I have been trying to connect and retrieve a list of data from Business Central.
The Web Service has been exposed from BC and the OData link works and displays the JSON for the data in "Articles".
I'm trying to consumer that Service with **NodeJS** using **NTLM** (i also tried basic authentication and the same issue persists.
Please find below the file responsible for consuming the BC Web Service followed by the 401 error.
I have already stored all the information needed for NTLM config in my .env file, I did try to hardcode them and the same issue

```
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");
const router = express.Router();
const ntlm = require("express-ntlm");
//const Article = require("../models/Articles.js");
const domain = process.env.DOMAIN;
const username = process.env.USERNAME;
const password = process.env.PASSWORD;

// Define auth function
const auth = ntlm({
  debug: console.log,
  domain,
  username,
  password,
  ntlm_version: 2,
  reconnect: true,
  send_401: function (res) {
    res.sendStatus(401);
  },
  badrequest: function (res) {
    res.sendStatus(400);
  },
});

// Get customer data from Business Central
async function getArticlesFromBC() {
  try {
    const options = {
      auth: {
        username,
        password,
        workstation: process.env.WORKSTATION,
        domain,
      },
    };
    const companyId = "CRONUS France S.A.";
    const encodedCompanyId = encodeURIComponent(companyId);
    const url = `http://${process.env.SERVER}:7048/BC210/ODataV4/Company('${encodedCompanyId}')/ItemListec`;
    const response = await axios.get(url, options);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw new Error("Error retrieving articles data from Business Central");
  }
}

// Route to get article data
router.get("/", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = req.ntlm;
    console.log(user);
    let articles = await getArticlesFromBC();
    res.json(articles);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res
      .status(500)
      .send("Error retrieving articles data from Business Central");
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Explanation**

- This is the auth function that will use the variables set in .env to authenticate the user in order to access the BC endpoint

```
// Define auth function
const auth = ntlm({
  debug: console.log,
  domain,
  username,
  password,
  ntlm_version: 2,
  reconnect: true,
  send_401: function (res) {
    res.sendStatus(401);
  },
  badrequest: function (res) {
    res.sendStatus(400);
  },
});
```

- This is the function that connects to the endpoint URL and returns the JSON file, this is where the error triggers

```
// Get article data from Business Central
async function getArticlesFromBC() {
  try {
    const options = {
      auth: {
        username,
        password,
        workstation: process.env.WORKSTATION,
        domain,
      },
    };
    const companyId = "CRONUS France S.A.";
    const encodedCompanyId = encodeURIComponent(companyId);
    const url = `http://${process.env.SERVER}:7048/BC210/ODataV4/Company('${encodedCompanyId}')/ItemListec`;
    const response = await axios.get(url, options);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw new Error("Error retrieving articles data from Business Central");
  }
}
```

- This is the route to access the nodejs api

```
// Route to get article data
router.get("/", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = req.ntlm;
    console.log(user);
    let articles = await getArticlesFromBC();
    res.json(articles);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res
      .status(500)
      .send("Error retrieving articles data from Business Central");
  }
});
```

**This is the 401 error json, you can see at the beginning that NTLM authenticates successfully but then it throws the catch block in the get function**

```
[express-ntlm] No Authorization header present
[express-ntlm] No domaincontroller was specified, all Authentication messages are valid.
{
  DomainName: 'DESKTOP-1EF91E4',
  UserName: 'ahmed',
  Workstation: 'DESKTOP-1EF91E4',
  Authenticated: true
}
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401
    at settle (D:\ESPRIT\5eme\PFE\B2B-ERP-MERN-App\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:1900:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (D:\ESPRIT\5eme\PFE\B2B-ERP-MERN-App\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:2944:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:412:35)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http' ],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function], Blob: null },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: AxiosHeaders {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/1.3.3',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
    },
    auth: {
      username: 'ahmed',
      password: undefined,
      workstation: 'DESKTOP-1EF91E4',
      domain: undefined
    },
    method: 'get',
    url: "http://desktop-1ef91e4:7048/BC210/ODataV4/Company('CRONUS%20France%20S.A.')/ItemListec",
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: false,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    _contentLength: 0,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    socket: Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'desktop-1ef91e4',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: null,
      _server: null,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 465,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    _header: "GET /BC210/ODataV4/Company('CRONUS%20France%20S.A.')/ItemListec HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/1.3.3\r\n' +
      'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
      'Host: desktop-1ef91e4:7048\r\n' +
      'Authorization: Basic YWhtZWQ6\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 80,
      protocol: 'http:',
      options: [Object],
      requests: {},
      sockets: [Object],
      freeSockets: {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'GET',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    path: "/BC210/ODataV4/Company('CRONUS%20France%20S.A.')/ItemListec",
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: [Socket],
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      headers: [Object],
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      trailers: {},
      rawTrailers: [],
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 401,
      statusMessage: 'Unauthorized',
      client: [Socket],
      _consuming: false,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      responseUrl: "http://ahmed:@desktop-1ef91e4:7048/BC210/ODataV4/Company('CRONUS%20France%20S.A.')/ItemListec",
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'desktop-1ef91e4',
    protocol: 'http:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 0,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: "http://ahmed:@desktop-1ef91e4:7048/BC210/ODataV4/Company('CRONUS%20France%20S.A.')/ItemListec",
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      'accept-encoding': [Array],
      host: [Array],
      authorization: [Array]
    }
  },
  response: {
    status: 401,
    statusText: 'Unauthorized',
    headers: AxiosHeaders {
      'content-length': '0',
      server: 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0',
      'www-authenticate': 'Negotiate',
      date: 'Thu, 16 Feb 2023 11:49:51 GMT',
      connection: 'close'
    },
    config: {
      transitional: [Object],
      adapter: [Array],
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 0,
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      env: [Object],
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      headers: [AxiosHeaders],
      auth: [Object],
      method: 'get',
      url: "http://desktop-1ef91e4:7048/BC210/ODataV4/Company('CRONUS%20France%20S.A.')/ItemListec",
      data: undefined
    },
    request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [Socket],
      _header: "GET /BC210/ODataV4/Company('CRONUS%20France%20S.A.')/ItemListec HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/1.3.3\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
        'Host: desktop-1ef91e4:7048\r\n' +
        'Authorization: Basic YWhtZWQ6\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: "/BC210/ODataV4/Company('CRONUS%20France%20S.A.')/ItemListec",
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'desktop-1ef91e4',
      protocol: 'http:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    data: ''
  }
}
Error: Error retrieving articles data from Business Central
    at getArticlesFromBC (D:\ESPRIT\5eme\PFE\B2B-ERP-MERN-App\routes\ArticleRoutes.js:44:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async D:\ESPRIT\5eme\PFE\B2B-ERP-MERN-App\routes\ArticleRoutes.js:53:20
```

Comment: Is your Business Central running On Premise or in the Cloud?

Comment: On Premise as the web service url indicates, it works when accessed on browser, yet when consumed as a 3rd party that happens

Comment: Is NTLM Authentication enabled on the Server Instance?

Comment: Yes it is, I switched to httpntlm instead of express-ntlm and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Even though it works perfectly in postman (NTLM authentication on Server Instance is enabled for that to happen)
express-ntlm seemed to authenticate the user but dosent follow up for some reason.
I switched to **httpntlm** and it worked perfectly, here is the new code in the node API file :

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const httpntlm = require("httpntlm");

// Get article data from Business Central
async function getArticlesFromBC() {
  const username = process.env.USERNAME;
  const password = process.env.PASSWORD;
  const domain = process.env.DOMAIN;
  const workstation = process.env.WORKSTATION;
  const encodedCompanyId = encodeURIComponent("CRONUS France S.A.");
  const url = `http://${process.env.SERVER}:7048/BC210/ODataV4/Company('${encodedCompanyId}')/ItemListec`;

  const options = {
    url: url,
    username: username,
    password: password,
    workstation: workstation,
    domain: domain
  };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    httpntlm.get(options, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(res.body);
      }
    });
  });
}

// Route to get article data
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const articles = await getArticlesFromBC();
    res.json(articles);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error retrieving articles data from Business Central:", error.message);
    res.status(500).send("Error retrieving articles data from Business Central");
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```